# Laravel retrieving morphToMany related children

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have M-to-M `morphToMany` relationship:

User::class has `morphToMany` Building::class through `buildable` table (Many Buildings can have many Users and many Users can have many Buildings)
*Building::class is used `morphToMany` with many classes*

```
building_id | buildable_type | buildable_id
1           | App\Models\User| 1
1           | App\Models\Car | 1
```

Each Building `hasMany` Floor::class

How can I select $user->floors and have a list with every floor that applies to the user?

I know I can select $user->building->floors, what if I want to write a direct relationship?

```
class User extends Model {

public function floors()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Floor::class,
        "buildable"
    );
}

}
```